# How to calculate inflection point in C# by a given function

Tags: c#, math, statistics, regression

My function always looks like this: `y = beta1 / (1 + exp(beta2 + beta3 * x))`. With the data it can get, it always looks like a mirror of that (it starts with high values, then decreases) [image]
I have the values beta1, beta2 and beta3. Now I need to calculate **the point of inflection**. I guess I could do it with an algorithm, but are there any functions provided by a library I could use? (Currently I cannot use Accord.NET because I still have C# 3.5 and it does only support 4.+)

**update** I'd be fine with a method to take the derivative ;)

Best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is second derivation, and if the function only differs in constants, you can pre-compute it somewhere, and then only fill in constants.

Here you are: [wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28a%20/%20%281%20%2b%20exp%28b%20%2b%20c%20%2a%20x%29%29%29%27%27)

There is no *standard* library function that derivates for you.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write an algorithm: the second derivative is null for x = - beta2 / beta3. There is a close solution to this problem.